# <canvas> gradient fade with 3 Colours

Tags: javascript, canvas, gradient

I have been experimenting with HTML5 and gradient fades, I would like to use 3 colours and gradually fade them into each other. Currently I can only get it working using two colours.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFayC/embedded/result/)

My target is something similar to this image:

[image: target image]

The colours should slowly fade into each other, i'm happy with the fade effect I currently have working, although would like to add a third colour.

I have tried to add an array of the colours to use, but the colour function was modded from a tutorial (will add link if I can find) and am not quite sure how to do it.

Could anyone offer any adivce?

Thanks in advance.

Am not trying to get it looking exactly the same as the image, but if I could just add another colour to my current version that should be fine.

**Edit**: Due to the confusion: I'm not looking for a "static" graident, if you view my example closely you will see a suttle fade effect. I want to achieve the same effect, but have the gradient with 3 colours and looking similar to the image above.

It should "shimmer" and a gradually fade. Offering a bounty as I'm struggling with creating this with 3 colours, which I think will be easy for most..

Comment: [This might help.](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Comment: Wait ... you're doing this in a `<canvas>` and not with the HTML5/CSS3 "linear-gradient" background style ...  is that what you prefer?

Comment: I want it to work in as many browsers as possible, and with using ex-canvas I was hoping to add support for IE. Is it possible to do a similar effect in HTML5/CSS3 with fading?

Comment: Well check that gradient generator site - it's got some provisions for IE, and it gives you what appears to be pretty portable CSS. (*edit* actually for older IE browsers it looks like it can't really do it, with only the old transform "filter" properties.)

Comment: @c69 The question is how to make those colours fade into each other?

Comment: @Elliott in that case you might want to supply us with working piece of code for two colors, at least.

Comment: The code does work, if you click on the jsFiddle provided ^. Takes a couple of seconds to see the effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless you need to do some complex animation, you were doing some extremely unnecessary calculations for your gradient. The point of the gradient is that you give it some seed values and it generates everything in between automatically.

I worked up a sample gradient that looks similar to your reference image: http://jsfiddle.net/ZFayC/2/

Note that it looks like your reference image might have a small amount of texture to it, and that the gradient definitely isn't linear. If you want to re-create the reference image, you'll have to use some radial gradients and possibly overlay a texture.

Also, note that you were setting the canvas `width` and `height` via CSS properties. With the canvas element, CSS `width` and `height` control the *magnification* of the element, while DOM-level attributes control the actual dimensions.

---

**Edit:** I completely missed the fact that you were looking to produce an animated gradient. My apologies for that.

I went back and edited my example to smoothly transition between three pre-defined colors similar to the ones in your reference image. You can view the updated example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fkU4Q/

Is this more along the lines of what you're looking for?

---

**Edit:** Here's another update that adds full-screen support, a diagonal gradient, and a secondary radial gradient that is overlaid in the middle to help give some variety:

http://jsfiddle.net/fkU4Q/2/

You might want to customize the colors a bit more to increase the variation, but hopefully the functionality is there now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that it looks good. Although my main problem was getting the colours to fade into each other, like my demo? Thanks.

Comment: @Elliott I don't quite follow what you're looking for. The colors in my example fade into one another. Am I missing something?

Comment: The fade is static, if you look at my example you will see the colours fade in and out of each other. Thats why I have all the extra code. Thanks.

Comment: @Elliott Ah, my apologies. I somehow completely missed the subtle color fluctuations in your example. I feel like you should be able to achieve what you're looking for by dynamically updating only the color values and keeping the stop locations the same. That would keep your code much cleaner and a lot more straight-forward. For example, `color1` shifts to `color2`, `color2` shifts to `color3`, and `color3` shifts to `color1` (and so on, around in a loop).

Comment: I have tried doing that and it seems to "jump" and isn't as smooth as it currently is - Now offering a bounty.

Comment: @Elliott I just edited my answer with an updated example that animates the gradient smoothly. Is this what you're after?

Comment: Really appreciate how fast you answered! It's almost perfect, is it possible to have it at a slight angle? As I will be using full page width it should go from top left corner to bottom right corner. Sorry it isn't very clear on the image.

It should'nt be directly in the corner (pink is about 40px down). One more thing could you change it so there isn't "one" solid colour e.g. in the middle there is sometimes one solid pink, they should always be blending in together. Hope that makes sense, other than that its great, thanks alot !

Comment: @Elliott Sure thing, no problem. I just edited my answer again with another update that adds what you're looking for, I think. The gradient is now diagonal and I added in a secondary radial gradient in the middle to help break up the colors more.

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you so much, just one slight problem - Not sure if it's just me but in Firefox (latest stable release) it seems to lag alot and becomes unresponsive unless the cursor is moved? It also seems to make the whole website crash, such as the slideshow I have added. Thanks again!

Comment: @Elliott I'm not sure what to tell you--I just opened the full-screen jsFiddle in the latest stable release of FF, Chrome, and IE and had the gradient animation running in all of them at the same time for quite a while without any issues. Maybe you have added some taxing logic with whatever else the site is running in addition to the background animation? Also, keep in mind that the example I worked up runs 10 times every second. You can try adjusting the delay passed to `setInterval()`, but it will change the speed of the animation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you suggest what "taxing" logic I could add? Also just out of interest was the code I produced actually any good or did I get the wrong idea? Accepting this as the answer as you have helped more than enough :)

Comment: @Elliott You're welcome, and thanks! Regarding the taxing logic, I was implying that maybe something on your site is impacting performance when paired with the background animation. JS is essentially a large event queue, so when you have an animation firing 10 times per second it can quickly bog things down. Your code was essentially performing the same task as mine--just stepping the colors incrementally. When I said you were doing unnecessary calculations, I didn't realize there was animation involved. I don't think you were that far off. :)

Comment: Thanks again, will look into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think by applying certain tricks it should not be a big deal using CSS3 properties here is the playground,

http://css3.mikeplate.com/